# Save data from *.dat into Python different lists

Tags: python, list

I have a .dat file with this data format:

[image: with this data format]

and I need to create a list variable for the first column, and another variable for the forth in Python 3.7.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
root = Tk() 
root.geometry('200x100') 
def open_file(): 
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('Measurement Files', '*.dat')]) 
    content = file.read() 
    cols = [[], [], [], [], []]
    for line in content.split('\n'): # loop over all data lines
            for n, col in enumerate(line.split()): # split each line into five columns and loop over
                cols[n].append(float(col)) # convert each data to float and append to corresponding column
                print(cols) 
btn = Button(root, text ='Open', command = lambda:open_file()) 
btn.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10) 
mainloop()
```

This is my code, it splitted the columns in different lists but, how can I create a variable for the 1st list, and another one for the fourth one? Once I try:

```
time=cols[0]
head=cols[3]
```

It says that 'cols' is not defined

Comment: Where do you try the code which leads to the error? Please share the full traceback. Have you read the docs? I'm not familiar with tkinter, but It seems like `askpopenfilename()` might be a better choice, since your data is in a tab-delimited format.

Comment: if you need only two columns then you could create only two lists `time = []` and `head = []` and skip inner loop - `items = line.split()` `time.append(float(items[0]))` `head.append(float(items[4]))`

Comment: where do you use `time=cols[0]` ? Variable `cols` is local variable and doesn't exists outside `open_file()`. If you need it outside then use `global cols` in function to inform funtion to use external/global variable instead of local one.

Comment: you can use `command=open_file` without `lambda` and without `()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cols` is local variable which exists only inside function and you would have to use `global cols` in function to assign values to external/global variabl

---

Minimal example with other changes

```
#from tkinter import * # `import *` is not preferred
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

# --- functions ---

def open_file():
    global time  # inform function to assign value to external/global variable
    global head  # inform function to assign value to external/global variable

    file = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('Measurement Files', '*.dat')]) 
    content = file.read() 
    time = []  # assing value to global variable
    head = []  # assing value to global variable
    for line in content.split('\n'):  # loop over all data lines
        items = line.split()  # split each line into five columns and loop over
        if len(items) >= 4:
            time.append(float(items[0]))
            head.append(float(items[3]))                    
            #print(time)  # get value from global variable
            #print(head)  # get value from global variable

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk() 
root.geometry('200x100') 

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Open', command=open_file) 
btn.pack(side='top', pady=10)

root.mainloop()

print(time)  # get value from global variable
print(head)  # get value from global variable
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I added this modification, I still get an error:

Comment: time.append(float(items[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I don't have your file to test it. Maybe some lines are empty. I added `if len(items) >= 4:` before getting `[0]` and `[3]`